# Installing Eigen to use in VS Code

Tags: eigen, libraries

This may be a relatively simple fix, but I am relatively new to C++ (and am not the best at understanding the intricacies of package management) but I'm trying to install the Eigen library to use for C++ matrix multiplies/linear algebra operations. I don't really know where to put the source code and how to make the include statement not give me an error (#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit). Can someone tell me a step by step process of how to make this work>

I tried placing the Eigen source code inside the same directory that my code is in, but this does not solve the issue.

Comment: What OS and development tools, besides VS Code, are you using? Use the right tools and you install Eigen with a package manager and then all you need to do is make  a couple edits to tasks.json and one to c_cpp_properties to tell VS Code to use the libraries. Use the wrong tools and you're really having to work.

Comment: I just installed the source code from their page into the same directory. I now realize that was not the correct thing to do. I have a Mac and have Homebrew, although the Eigen page said you simply needed to install the source code, whatever that means.

Comment: I don't know homebrew, not a Mac user, but you should be able to do something along the lines of `brew install eigen` to get the libraries prebuilt and ready to go.